# difference between the two ways of using aes in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I recently started learning R but am confused with the aes feature in ggplot2.

I have seen two different places where aes is placed in the code.

```
ggplot(data = mpg) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy))

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) +
  geom_point()
```

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: I think there's a dupe for this (looking for it), but the main difference is that `aes()` in the top layer will be inherited by subsequent layers by default, but when specified in a `geom` layer it is specific to that layer only.

Comment: That explains a lot. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DhruvRaghunath: fyi there is also a `inherit.aes =` option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't find a dupe, so here's an answer:

Aesthetics specified in `ggplot()` are inherited by subsequent layers. Aesthetics specified in particular layers are specific only to that layer. Here's an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth()

ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_smooth()  # error, geom_smooth needs its own aesthetics
```

This is mostly useful when you want different layers to have different specifications, for example these two plots are different, you have to decide which you want:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth()

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_smooth()
```

On individual layers, you can use `inherit.aes = FALSE` to turn off inheritance for that layer. This is very useful if most of your layers use the same aesthetics, but a few do not.